# Having trouble to installing the Debug app in Emulator and also in real device in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My release app is running completely fine and i have also used this Debug app before but all of a sudden my Debug app is not installing in the emulator and also in the real device.Its showing a warning(snap shot is given below) when i am installing the Debug app and when i am pressing OK then android studion showing the error(snap shot is given below). I have attached two snap shot of errors.Help needed.

[image: Snap shot of warning window from android studio]

[image: Snap shot of error message from android studio]

Comment: And did you uninstall the app?

Comment: yes i did but did not work

Comment: @MohammadHelalUddin I think I had a problem like this and disabling instant run did the trick. Can you try to disable it ?

Comment: Oh! you just saved a day for me .its working fine for me right now . thank you so much @andrei

Comment: @MohammadHelalUddin glad I could help